# Сгенирировать 2-мерный массив 5х4 и отсортировать его 3 столбец по возрастанию

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Нужно создать 2-мерный массив 5х4 и отсортировать 3-й столбец по возрастанию.
Я пробовал писать код:

```java
int[][] a = new int[5][4];
int b;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
}
System.out.println("Массив:");
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("a[" + i + "][" + j + "]=" + a[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
            if (a[i][j] > a[i][k]) {
                b = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[i][k];
                a[i][k] = b;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Массив выводится, но не сортируется, выскакивает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at twomasiws.Masiws.main(Masiws.java:32)
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at twomasiws.Masiws.main(Masiws.java:32)
```

Переходим на строку *32*

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) // line 32
```

Вы здесь создаёте вложенный цикл, но условием завершения ставите `a.length`, а это количество строк в матрице. Через какое-то время цикл попытается получить элемент `[0][4]` из матрицы размером `[5][4]` и конечно выйдет за её границы.

Вы ведь в цикле, который заполняет массив верно указали условие завершение внутреннего цикла `for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)`, так и используйте его дальше.

С квадратной матрицей бы сработало, но... *5x4* - не квадрат.

(в последнем цикле, который выводит массив - та же проблема)

---

Второе:
вы пишете

> Нужно создать 2-мерный массив 5х4 и отсортировать **3-й столбец** по возрастанию

А фактически сортируете весь массив.

---

Я бы вообще предложил вот такое решение:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[5][4];
        Random rand = new Random();
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(flatArray -> Arrays.setAll(flatArray, element -> rand.nextInt(32768)));

        System.out.println("The original array: " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
        Arrays.sort(array[2]);

        System.out.println("Array with sorted 3rd column: " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

- Тут скорее всего вам многое непонятно, давайте разбираться:

```java
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(flatArray -> Arrays.setAll(flatArray, element -> rand.nextInt(32768)));
```

Используем `Stream API` <sub>(ну... а почему бы и нет?)</sub>

`forEach()` перебирает все массивы внутри матрицы, и для каждого из них вызывает лямбду:

```
flatArray -> Arrays.setAll(flatArray, element -> rand.nextInt(32768))
```

Здесь метод `setAll` устанавливает всем элементам массива случайные значения, полученные из `rand.nextInt()`

Все это можно заменить вот таким кодом:

```java
for (int[] flatArray : array) {
    Arrays.setAll(flatArray, element -> rand.nextInt(32768));
}
```

или

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = rand.nextInt(32768);
    }
}
```

- Далее

`Arrays.deepToString(array)` просто переведёт матрицу в строку, чтобы не писать стандартный цикл вывода.

- Теперь сортировка:

`Arrays.sort(array[2])`

отсортирует 3й столбец матрицы

(можно заменить своим методом, тем же `Bubble Sort`, как у вас, но... <s>мы ж ленивые</s> будем пользоваться уже готовым методом сортировки)

- И снова вывод на консоль, с помощью уже знакомого вам `Arrays.deepToString(array)`

---

Вот вроде и всё, надеюсь, будет понятно `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки массивов можно использовать метод [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)):

```java
int[][] a = new int[5][4];

// заполняем массив
IntStream.range(0, 44)
        .filter(i -> i % 10 < 4)
        .forEach(i -> a[i / 10][i % 10] = (int) (Math.random() * 100));

// выводим получившийся массив
Arrays.stream(a).forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
// [85, 72, 51, 80]
// [32, 81, 40, 67]
// [80, 32, 13, 94]
// [52, 12, 37, 49]
// [11, 8, 4, 81]

// сортируем массив по третьей колонке
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[2]));

// выводим отсортированный массив
Arrays.stream(a).forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
// [11, 8, 4, 81]
// [80, 32, 13, 94]
// [52, 12, 37, 49]
// [32, 81, 40, 67]
// [85, 72, 51, 80]
```

---

Если нужно отсортировать только третью колонку, а все остальное оставить на прежних местах:

```java
// выгружаем третью колонку и сортируем
int[] sorted = Arrays.stream(a).mapToInt(arr -> arr[2]).sorted().toArray();

// загружаем обратно
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> a[i][2] = sorted[i]);
```

Неотсортированный массив:

```
[58, 19, 91, 70]
[27, 32, 28, 8]
[11, 40, 55, 11]
[57, 44, 8, 47]
[49, 90, 83, 89]
```

Отсортирована третья колонка:

```
[58, 19, 8, 70]
[27, 32, 28, 8]
[11, 40, 55, 11]
[57, 44, 83, 47]
[49, 90, 91, 89]
```